# Automatic destroy of global vectors

Tags: c++

I have a case where I am declaring an std::vector as global. Precisely, vector is an collection of std::list, which is collection of int.

```
std::vector<std::list<int> >
```

I am making it global in one file under an namespace. Like:

```
namespace SPACE_1 {
  std::vector<std::list<int> > vec_1;

  class CLASS_1 {
    // And inside this class I have some functions which
    // populates this vec_1
  }
}
```

When my work is done, I clear the vector using this code(inside an function)

```
std::vector<std::list<int> >::iterator it = vec_1.begin();
for (; it != vec_1.end(); ++it) {
  (*it).clear();
}
vec_1.clear();
```

Make sense till now?

At the end of main, destructor of that vector gets called, which is fine, and it assert for some reason. Not able to understand why! I understand that it calls destructor but not why does it crashes.

You might say that why I am clearing this up and should be automatically handled when program ends. Yes, I concur but I wanted to understand this case.

Little help?

Comment: Do you get any error message? What compiler version and flags do you use?

Comment: did you try to call ```vec_1.clear();``` without loop?

Comment: Why do you use `nl_net` with your iterator `it`, when there is `int` in the vector definition? What is `nl_net`?

Comment: You don't need all that code to clear the vector.  Just `vec_1.clear()` is all you need.

Comment: @Alexander, No I did not try that. How will it benefit?

Comment: @DanielLangr, Sorry. My bad. Consider it an as type. Edited the question.

Comment: @RahulBhargava -- Writing a loop like that indicates you're not aware of how C++ and classes with destructors work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, May be. What if std::list is an collection of pointers? Need to clear it iteratively, then.

Comment: @RahulBhargava if the issue is in the inconsistency of the iterator types - it will fix it

Comment: @RahulBhargava So, does your version with `int` causes the error as well? Or, only the version with `nl_net`? Could you create a _complete reproducible and verifiable example_?

Comment: @RahulBhargava But it isn't a list of pointers.  Don't write code when it is not necessary.  All that will do is have more potential for bugs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Yeah. May be I am not great in C++. That is why I came here.

Comment: @DanielLangr, It is the same problem. nl_net was just an typo.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, In this case, no. May be vec_1.clear() will suffice. But if you have pointers as part of std::list, then what do you do. #justasking.

Comment: I suggest getting rid altogether of that loop.  Either call simply `clear()`, or let the vector destroy itself.  By doing that, you would be eliminating the chance that it is code you produced that caused the error.  If the error still occurs, then it is something else your program is doing that is potentially corrupting the memory.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem: https://wandbox.org/permlink/krB4uZAvO1qE06Bv. Could you edit it to trigger the error you are encountering? BTW, you still did not specify that assertion error. Please, paste the error message into your (edited) question.

Comment: Ideally, use a list of smart pointers instead. If you _must_ have owning raw pointers then yes, you need to manually clean them up - but it should be rare.

Comment: Just do `vec_1.clear();`.  Copy the actual error text.  If you have pointers involved, they should be smart pointers.